# @ElementCollection in hibernate query

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hi i'm trying to use an element collection in a custom constructor in hibernate + spring boot. Here's the query:

````
``` @Query("SELECT NEW Profile(p.id, p.enabledTargetUsages, p.country, p.userCard) from Profile p where p.id IN (?1)")```
````

where enabledTargetUsage is like this in Profile entity

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "profile_enabled", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id"))
@Column(name = "target_usage")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Set<EmobilityUtils.TargetUsage> enabledTargetUsages;
```

but when it gets translated into SQL there are some issues:

```
, . as col_9_0_, profile0_.country
```

and i get error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
```

Any ideas why the field just disappear in sql translation?

Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}

Spring Boot Version: 1.5.7.RELEASE

DB is postgre